# Capture output of data

Tags: r

I want to capture the output from the `data` function in which you supply a package name and the function produces a static output.  I want to turn this into a dataframe.

Currently the following gives the static output:

```
data(package = "ggplot2")
```

I'd like it to be as a dataframe and actually never have the external static output produced.

```
diamonds                Prices of 50,000 round cut diamonds
economics               US economic time series.
midwest                 Midwest demographics.
movies                  Movie information and user ratings from IMDB.com.
mpg                     Fuel economy data from 1999 and 2008 for 38 popular models of car
msleep                  An updated and expanded version of the mammals sleep dataset.
presidential            Terms of 10 presidents from Eisenhower to Bush W.
seals                   Vector field of seal movements.
```

Comment: Something like `as.data.frame(data()[[3]][, 3:4])`?

Comment: almost but this would be for a specific package.

Comment: You might also like this page that catalogues R datasets from a bunch of pakcages: http://vincentarelbundock.github.com/Rdatasets/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is this enough to get you started?

```
> data(package = "ggplot2")$results
     Package   LibPath                  Item          
[1,] "ggplot2" "/home/mrdwab/R/library" "diamonds"    
[2,] "ggplot2" "/home/mrdwab/R/library" "economics"   
[3,] "ggplot2" "/home/mrdwab/R/library" "midwest"     
[4,] "ggplot2" "/home/mrdwab/R/library" "movies"      
[5,] "ggplot2" "/home/mrdwab/R/library" "mpg"         
[6,] "ggplot2" "/home/mrdwab/R/library" "msleep"      
[7,] "ggplot2" "/home/mrdwab/R/library" "presidential"
[8,] "ggplot2" "/home/mrdwab/R/library" "seals"       
     Title                                                              
[1,] "Prices of 50,000 round cut diamonds"                              
[2,] "US economic time series."                                         
[3,] "Midwest demographics."                                            
[4,] "Movie information and user ratings from IMDB.com."                
[5,] "Fuel economy data from 1999 and 2008 for 38 popular models of car"
[6,] "An updated and expanded version of the mammals sleep dataset."    
[7,] "Terms of 10 presidents from Eisenhower to Bush W."                
[8,] "Vector field of seal movements."
```

Obviously, to get a `data.frame` of just the "Item" and "Title" data, you can use:

```
> data.frame(data(package = "ggplot2")$results)[-c(1, 2)]
          Item                                                             Title
1     diamonds                               Prices of 50,000 round cut diamonds
2    economics                                          US economic time series.
3      midwest                                             Midwest demographics.
4       movies                 Movie information and user ratings from IMDB.com.
5          mpg Fuel economy data from 1999 and 2008 for 38 popular models of car
6       msleep     An updated and expanded version of the mammals sleep dataset.
7 presidential                 Terms of 10 presidents from Eisenhower to Bush W.
8        seals                                   Vector field of seal movements.
```

Comment: How about getting result of changepoint (cpt.mean) and its plotted (plot(xyz)) values?

Comment: @bjan, I'm not sure how your comment is related to this question... Is `cpt.mean` a function in a specific package and you're trying to extract its values? If so, I'd start at the help page and see if it specifies what sort of value is returned (usually in a section called "Value").

Comment: i was trying to get the change points calculated by cpt.mean() back into C#. I have sorted it out, thanks.