# Exclude from autocomplete data object from packes in R not in the global environment

Tags: r, package, rstudio

Is there a way to remove from the autocomplete all objects associated to libraries that are not in the global environment, aside from their functions?

For example the plyr package loads baseball. I want to remove all these dataframe loaded by packages because I don't want them in memory and also because the autocomplete function looks through all these objects that I never use.

Is there code or an option to remove these objects systematically or force libraries only to load their functions and the strictly necessary objects?

Comment: # CLear R environment and all the loaded files 

rm(list = ls()) 
gc

Comment: This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838360/how-to-import-only-one-function-from-another-package-without-loading-the-entire

Comment: Also this might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27709936/get-a-list-of-the-data-sets-in-a-particular-package

Comment: For what it's worth: Datasets that come with packages are *not* automatically loaded into memory upon loading the library. Only `data(baseball)` loads `baseball` into the current R environment  (which you can check with `ls()`).

Comment: @Hunaidkhan sorry but no, that removes MY objects and doesn't remove the rest.

Comment: @MauritsEvers you are correct, the objects are not in the environment, but I need to exclude them from the RStudio auto complete. This might be an RStudio issue.