# What is the data structure of the output that contains only the data sets?

Tags: r, data-structures, dataset

I have installed "MASS" and "ggplot2" package. Please help me with a command to know the data structure of output that contains only datasets.

Comment: It's all explained in an answer here. Possible duplicate of [Get a list of the data sets in a particular package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27709936/get-a-list-of-the-data-sets-in-a-particular-package).

Comment: You've already asked three duplicate questions and risk a temporary question ban(don't know if it still exists). Anyways, I suggest that you first make some research before asking.

Answer (score 0):

This basic r function shows the datasets that you have available.

```
data()
```

If you see the dataset you want from this list, then load that dataset for use:

```
data("Name_of_Dataset")
```

If you don't find the dataset you need, then do a web search for that dataset.  Usually most of the commonly found tutorials are using datasets that can be easily found and downloaded.