# data set "eset" not found in the library genefilter

Tags: r, error-handling

I was practicing R language exercises when I encountered a question that required me to access the "`eset`" dataset in the "`genefilter`" library.;

```
> library(genefilter)
> data(eset)
```

But I always get the following error;

```
In data(eset) : data set ‘eset’ not found
```

I encountered the same error in;

```
>library(globaltest);
>data(exampleX);
>data(exampleY);
```

Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong here?

I searched through all the `BiocManager` documentation but couldn't find a helpful answer.

Comment: Perhaps the package has changed since the exercises were written, or you have an old version of the package.  You should be able to list the data sets in the package with `data(package='genefilter')` - what does it show? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/27709936 for more info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very wild guess.

Searching on the [Biobase github repo for commits referring to 'eset'](https://github.com/Bioconductor/Biobase/search?q=eset+data&type=commits) suggests that this is a very old example, and that (running `data(package = "Biobase")` for more information) that you *may* be able to move forward via

```r
data(sample.ExpressionSet, package = "Biobase")
eset <- sample.ExpressionSet
```

Comment: can't help you; there doesn't seem to be any useful searching for ["example" in the github repo](https://github.com/jellegoeman/globaltest/search?q=example), nor does globaltest have a NEWS file (so @IRTFM's answer won't help).  I was able to guess the answer to your first question; for the second, **we definitely can't help without more context**.

Answer (score 3):

Here's some code for reading the package "Biobase" news file and finding information within it:

```
> txt <- news(package="Biobase")
> str(txt)
Classes ‘news_db’ and 'data.frame': 30 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Version : chr  "2.37" "2.33" "2.31" "2.31" ...
 $ Date    : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Category: chr  "BUG FIXES" "BUG FIXES" "NEW FEATURES" "NEW FEATURES" ...
 $ Text    : chr  "'$' completion on eSet and ExpressionSet works in RStudio." "exprs<- enforces value with correct dim, dimnames." "tab completion implemented for eSet classes" "head and tail.AnnotatedDataFrame methods introduced" ...
 - attr(*, "bad")= logi [1:30] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 - attr(*, "package")= chr "Biobase"
> grep("eset", txt$Text)
[1] 30
> txt$Text[30]
[1] "Defunct data sets\n   1) bbsym\n   2) eset - use sample.ExpressionSet instead\n   
      3) golubMergeSub\n   4) sample.eSet - use sample.MultiSet instead\n   
      4) sample.exprSet.1 - use sample.ExpressionSet instead\n   
      5) sample.exprSet - use sample.ExpressionSet instead\n   6) SWPD\n   7) swrep"
```