# How to load a particular data set from a package in R?

Tags: r, dataset

In a [tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/survival-analysis-R) for the `survival` package there is an example of the 'ovarian' data set. It should be loaded with `data(ovarian)` but it returns

```
Warning message:
In data(ovarian): data set ‘ovarian’ not found
```

according to [Missing "ovarian" dataset in "survival" package](https://community.rstudio.com/t/missing-ovarian-dataset-in-survival-package/103414) I learned the data is there but under a different name. Based on [Get a list of the data sets in a particular package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27709936/get-a-list-of-the-data-sets-in-a-particular-package) I listed the data sets:

```
> data(package = "survival")$results[, "Item"]
 [1] "aml (cancer)"            "bladder (cancer)"        "bladder1 (cancer)"       "bladder2 (cancer)"       "cancer"                 
 [6] "capacitor (reliability)" "cgd"                     "cgd0 (cgd)"              "colon (cancer)"          "cracks (reliability)"   
[11] "diabetic"                "flchain"                 "gbsg (cancer)"           "genfan (reliability)"    "heart"                  
[16] "hoel (cancer)"           "ifluid (reliability)"    "imotor (reliability)"    "jasa (heart)"            "jasa1 (heart)"          
[21] "kidney (cancer)"         "leukemia (cancer)"       "logan"                   "lung (cancer)"           "mgus (cancer)"          
[26] "mgus1 (cancer)"          "mgus2 (cancer)"          "myeloid (cancer)"        "myeloma (cancer)"        "nafld1 (nafld)"         
[31] "nafld2 (nafld)"          "nafld3 (nafld)"          "nwtco"                   "ovarian (cancer)"        "pbc"                    
[36] "pbcseq (pbc)"            "rats (cancer)"           "rats2 (cancer)"          "retinopathy"             "rhDNase"                
[41] "rotterdam (cancer)"      "solder"                  "stanford2 (heart)"       "survexp.mn (survexp)"    "survexp.us (survexp)"   
[46] "survexp.usr (survexp)"   "tobin"                   "transplant"              "turbine (reliability)"   "udca"                   
[51] "udca1 (udca)"            "udca2 (udca)"            "uspop2 (survexp)"        "valveSeat (reliability)" "veteran (cancer)"
```

and found it `[34]` but I can't find how to load only this one. Can anyone help?
`data(ovarian (cancer))`, `data("ovarian (cancer)")`, `data(package = "survival")[34]` , `data(list = "ovarian (cancer)", package = "survival")` do not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use:

```
df <- survival::ovarian
```

*UPDATE from Roland's input.*

if you load the survival package, you can call `ovarian` like this and this should still work because of lazy-loading:

```
library(survival)

df <- ovarian
```

Comment: That's not necessary. If the package is loaded, they can just use `ovarian`. The main point is that the `data` function isn't needed because the survival package nowadays lazy-loads the datasets.